# I want to purposefully dry up (polymerize) an entire bottle of ethyl cyanoacrylate (Super Glue). How to do it?

Tags: polymers, plastics, drying

So, I want to do some tests with the solid form of ethyl cyanoacrylate.

I have a small 20g bottle which was very cheap so I don't mind.

How can I cause the entire contents of the bottle to set and turn solid?
I know CA glues require moisture to polymerize, and that after some time it will eventually dry out...
Will just leaving the bottle open in air work? Can I do something to speed it up?

Comment: Polymerization of cyanoacrylate in contact with wet air should last a couple of minutes. No need to speed it up.

Comment: My problem is usually keeping a once-opened bottle of superglue un-polymerized...

Comment: All right then. Will just keep then cap off and wait for moisture and air to do their thing.

Comment: Sorry. I meant "The" cap off...

Comment: Exercise caution while working with cyanoacrylate. A part of population is shown to have allergic reaction to it on dermal exposure. Also, cyanoacrylate fumes can sometimes be toxic.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to polymerize the CA in the bottle, because then you will have to peel/pry the bottle material away, and the interior of the polymer mass could still be fluid if you do not wait long enough.

First, prepare a plan. For instance, arrange some barriers on waxed paper, say, birthday candles or some disposable sticks, or put waxed paper into a small box (as if you were preparing to bake a cake) to make a rectangle. Then pour the CA glue onto the waxed paper and let it harden in air. The thickness of the layer will determine how long you have to wait. After hardening, you can peel the waxed paper away, leaving a coupon which you can cut or test in various ways.

You really need good ventilation when spreading CA out; allergies and sensitization are common.

You can pour the CA onto glass fiber or sawdust or sand to make a composite material. Some of these combinations react exothermically, and emit much vapor/smoke; therefore the need for good ventilation to avoid breathing the vapors. Sounds like fun. Other polymerizable materials have literature available and commercial products will come in larger sizes and might be good to work with too.